# How to get the string store in an array in php

Tags: php

I have a string that I trim first to remove extra characters and store it to a variable.

sampel output:

```
    variable: place1 place2
```

Now what I want to do is store it to an array. But how can I do that? is there a function that will detect if there is a white space? because every white space that it detects I would want the string to be stored in an array.

Any method or help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is this a PHP, JavaScript, or jQuery question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is the function you're looking for.

```
$string = 'place1 place2';
$arr = explode(' ', $string);
```

Comment: Thanks! So thats how it is, haha! :D

Comment: oh! so that's how it is.. LOL! I just found out. hahaha

Answer (score 2):

Use [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$array_of_parts = explode(' ', 'place1 place2');
echo $array_of_parts[0]; // place1
echo $array_of_parts[1]; // place2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use explode() function:

```
$yourString = 'place1 place2';
$exploded = explode (' ', $yourString);
echo $exploded[0];
echo $exploded[1];
```